# javascript countdown update db and refresh

Tags: php, javascript, countdown

can someone please help me with js/ajax countdown i want a countdown timer to 10 sec then update the database and refresh the page once it hits to 0.

i'm not really good with javascript/ajax, here is what i got so far:

```
var ss = 10;
function countdown() {
ss = ss-1;
if (ss<0) {
var url='update.php?countdown='+countdown;
}
else {
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML=ss;
window.setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
}
}

<span id="countdown" style="color:green;">10</span>
```

and update.php file, witch works fine:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['countdown'])) {     
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO num (id, ad, active) 
  VALUES ('1', 'Test',1)") or die(mysql_error());
  }
```

and also this is what i found http://pastebin.com/Qwz3Zqtt , works fine but i don't know how to put them together.

any helps would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You want a cool down timer running on the screen and when time is out to do a sql query ?

Comment: yes, like a simple countdown from 10 to 0 sec once the timer is done do sql or use var url='update.php?countdown='+countdown; , like here http://pastebin.com/Qwz3Zqtt on line 184

Comment: What should be in countdown variable? And, do you want page refresh, AFTER db update? Btw, nice and simple countdown: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/ - you just have to use <body onload="countdown_init()"> instead buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to learn basic ajax to process the database request. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) has [a very easy to use implementation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

The basic code could be something like:

```
<script>
function updateTimer(seconds){
    var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
    countdown.innerHTML = "Please wait " + seconds + " seconds.";
}

var timer = function() {
    var seconds = 10;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if (seconds <= 0){
            countdown.innerHTML = "Finished.. Updating Database";
            // AJAX request here
            clearInterval(interval);
        }else{
            updateTimer(seconds);            
            --seconds;
        }
    }, 1000);
    updateTimer(seconds);    
    --seconds;
}

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', timer);
</script>

<div id="countdown"></div>
<button id="start">Click Me</button>
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpse8/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)

Simplest example:

```
if (ss<0) {
    $.ajax('update.php?countdown='+countdown);
}
```